# .Net Framework 4 installation-failed

Tags: .net, installation

I want to install .Net framework 4 on Windows 7 32 bits but i got this error message:

> .NET Framework 4 has not been installed because HRESULT 0xc8000222

Do you know this message ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you have Windows Update issue while installing, Follow these steps to fix the problem:

- in Command line tool type net stop wuauserv (and click enter of course)
- Open Run command and type %windir% (and click enter), a window will be opened
- Rename the file SoftwareDistribution to SDold
- in Command line tool type net start wuauserv (and click enter of course)

After you do that the installation will be done successfully.

Comment: Thanks i installed it with success

Comment: Can you also explain why?

Answer (score 1):

Answer from [Microsoft](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_update/problem-installing-net-framework-4-hresult/bfac5cac-10e8-4eb9-b87d-64a3266522f7), next time ask google first ;)

1. Does the issue persist only with .netframework?
2. How are you  installing it? Is it through windows update or manually?

   a: Click Start > Run.

   b: Type cmd and press Enter. Please run the
   following command in the opened window. net stop WuAuServ

   c: Click
   Start > Run Type %windir% and press Enter.

   d: In the opened folder,
   rename the folder SoftwareDistribution to SDold.

   e: Click Start> Run type cmd and press Enter. Please run the following command in the opened window. net start WuAuServ

Remember running the cmd as administrator

Answer (score 0):

1. Does the issue persist only with .netframework?
2. How are you  installing it? Is it through windows update or manually?

a: Click Start > Run.
b: Type cmd and press Enter.
Please run the following command in the opened window.
net stop WuAuServ
c: Click Start > Run Type %windir% and press Enter.
d: In the opened folder, rename the folder SoftwareDistribution to SDold.

e: Click Start> Run type cmd and press Enter.
Please run the following command in the opened window.
net start WuAuServ

Hope this information helps.

Comment: Right click on cmd.exe and run it as administrator

Answer (score 0):

Many months with the same issue - other MS updates install correctly but .NET 4.7 failed each time. Tried all above suggestions and step by steps but still failed each time.

Now success, but more by accident; in resolving other PC performance and BSOD issues I found that my Western Digital backup drive app services were hogging all performance metrics (disk, memory, cpu). Everything grinding to a halt. Completely uninstalled ALL WD services, apps, processes etc. Performance back to normal. Attempted Windows Update installs with crossed fingers. .NET installed correctly and now latest version (Win 7 Pro).

Answer (score -1):

Type net stop wuauserv as administrator in cmd and enter
 Open Run command and type %windir% and enter
 Rename the file SoftwareDistribution to SDold
 Type net start wuauserv and enter in cmd

And there's the solution.