# Error hresult 0xc8000222 in Net Framework installation c# setup file

Tags: c#

I create a set up file. I attach .Net Framework 4 client profile along with the setup file creation.I am trying to install it on other machine it will not in work properly. It will produce error

> error hresult 0xc8000222

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.Net Framework 4 installation-failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27938412/net-framework-4-installation-failed)

Comment: i couldnt rename the SoftwareDistribution folder.Show a message 'The folder or file in it is open in another program'

Comment: i install my setup file in 3 machines. Installation successfully completed in 2 machines. But one  installation failed with an error message. 'you first must install one of the following version of the .net framework v4.0.30319'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the steps here..........
I just googled it....try that next time....

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/problem-installing-net-framework-4-hresult/bfac5cac-10e8-4eb9-b87d-64a3266522f7

Comment: i couldnt rename the SoftwareDistribution folder.Show a message 'The folder or file in it is open in another program'

Comment: i tested my setup file in two machines. it works properly. But another one is report an error.'you  first must install one of the following version of the .net framework v4.0.30319'

Comment: Yes - if your programs requires a .net framework - you will need to install int.  As fo the folder is in use - you must have had something still open.

Comment: I installed .Net framework 4 in all systems. It installed successfully. After that I am trying to install my setup file the error  message occured.